# \pgfplotstableread dynamically create loaded table macro from \pgfplotsinvokeforeach key

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, pgfplotstable

I am trying to load a whole lot of CSV's using `\pgfplotstableread` and dynamically assign them a macro name from a `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` loop.
I tried `\csname` but suspect this is totally the wrong approach!

```
\newcommand{\PlotsAuto}[1]{
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{NoGender,Female,Male}{
    \pgfplotstableread{../Data/My#1data-##1.csv}{\csname \##1\endcsname}
  }
}
```

I cannot do it with `\foreach` as the loaded tables would be local to that environment. (I tried with `\foreach \gender/\name in {NoGender/\NoGender....` with no success)

And then how can I access these in future loops which create the graphs?

Comment: remove the backslash from `##1` and use only one e.g. `#1`

Comment: @percusse, with: ``\pgfplotstableread{../Data/Mydata-##1.csv}{\csname #1\endcsname}`` I get an error: ``'too many }'s`` and ``Extra \endcsname \PlotsAuto``

Comment: Also edited question to fully reflect the command, using #1 in the filename worked when manually doing ``\pgfplotstableread`` for every line, how can this work when using #1 from ``pgfplotsinvokeforeach``?

Comment: ...also if (as it sometimes does) the filename contains a number straight after where the ``##1`` would be expanded. i.e. ``MySubData-NoGender2yr.csv``, how can I handle this as it looks like ``My{}Data-##12yr.csv`

Comment: Put a space afterwards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be an expansion issue as usual. But please don't do this number involving macro stuff. It is really unnecessary complication. Consider a batch file name treatment instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Myreddata-Female4yr.csv}
a b
1 2
3 4
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{Myreddata-Male23.csv}
a b
5 6
7 8
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\PlotsAuto}[1]{%
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{Female4yr,Male23}{%
    \begingroup\edef\temp{%
       \endgroup\noexpand\pgfplotstableread{My#1data-##1.csv}{\csname ##1\endcsname}}%
    \temp%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\PlotsAuto{red}
\expandafter\pgfplotstabletypeset\csname Male23\endcsname
\expandafter\pgfplotstabletypeset\csname Female4yr\endcsname
\end{document}
```

[image]